# Sending a RAM kit (electronic device) that was bought in the US to the EU, any special customs/papers?

Tags: shipping, electrical-goods

I'm an US citizen, currently in the EU. My friend has bought a RAM kit for me (PC - electronics computers) and is planning on shipping it to me through UPS. I was wondering if, besides the basic customs that UPS generates, I would need something else specifically for this piece of hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pay VAT, which amount is 20% of the product value. The transporter might add a 'custom processing' fee.

There does not seem to be special custom tariff for RAM (see https://trade.ec.europa.eu/access-to-markets/en/results?product=85423239&origin=US&destination=FR for example)